# How to open some pages by one HyperLink item?

Tags: c#, hyperlink, telerik, navigateurl

I have an array of some URL links. And I need to open all theese links by clicking  one HyperLink, located in cell of Telerik GridHyperLinkColumn. 
Is there any method to do this?
Now I have a code which sets first way to my HyperLink:

```
HyperLink link = (HyperLink) item["documents"].Controls[0];
            if (link.NavigateUrl.Contains(";"))
            {
                string[] linktext = link.NavigateUrl.Split(';');
                link.NavigateUrl = linktext[0];
            }
```

Comment: These can be achieved by calling all urls in a javascript method and call that javascript method in hyperlink onclick event

Comment: Can you give an example of the such js function, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably take a quick look at this SO answer [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5567017/4486115)

The takeaway is that this is not possible without using JavaScript functions:

> Without JavaScript, it's not possible to open two pages by clicking
>   one link unless both pages are framed on the one page that opens from
>   clicking the link. With JS it's trivial.

The example is this:

```
<p><a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://google.com');
    window.open('http://yahoo.com');">Click to open Google and Yahoo</a></p>
```

This would also work: ([again see answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20737794/4486115))

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="location.href='http://www.yahoo.com';" target="_blank">Open Two Links With One Click</a>
```